# JBoss issues while porting apps from Log4J to Log4J2

Tags: java, maven, jboss, log4j, log4j2

I've ported  from `Log4J` to `Log4J2` some applications that run in a servergroup under `JBoss 7.1.0` control.

The new applications are all correctly built by `maven`, but when I deploy some of them on the JBoss system (using jboss-cli.sh) the deployment results with an issue similar to that in the following lines where I understand that log4j2 is not available for the application.

> {"WFLYDC0074: Operation failed or was rolled back on all servers.
> Server failures:" => {"server-group" => {"XXXservergroupA" => {"host"
> => {"e2ebbfpsapp1" => {"XXXserverA1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
> {"jboss.deployment.subunit."ProxyControlEAR.ear"."ProxyControl.jar".POST_MODULE"
> => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "ProxyControl.jar" of deployment "ProxyControlEAR.ear"
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYSRV0177: Error getting reflective information for class
> com.mygrp.xxx.proxy.control.DocctrlServiceManager with ClassLoader
> ModuleClassLoader for Module
> "deployment.ProxyControlEAR.ear.ProxyControl.jar" from Service
> Module Loader
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Logger;
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger from [Module
> "deployment.ProxyControlEAR.ear.ProxyControl.jar" from Service
> Module Loader]"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not
> installed:" =>
> ["jboss.deployment.unit."ProxyControlEAR.ear".beanmanager"],"WFLYCTL0180:
> Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" =>
> ["jboss.deployment.unit."ProxyControlEAR.ear".weld.weldClassIntrospector
> is missing
> [jboss.deployment.unit."ProxyControlEAR.ear".beanmanager]"]}}}}}}}

The new application has been modified in conformity of the import method used for the old version, then the new pom.xml contains dependencies for log4J2-api and log4J2-core instead of lthe log4J alone and the SW has been modified to use the new log4j2 package.

Some apps to deploy (jar,ear,war), both the new and the old versions, doesn't contains log4j related jars. But the old version is always correctly deployed, while the new has issues (see above).

Can the new jar: log4j2-api and log4j2-core to be installed under JBoss (in the JBoss environment - where)?

If it need such a installation how am I allowed to do it?

Comment: Where do you have the dependencies defined? From the message it looks like an EJB JAR needs the dependency on it. This means the log4j libraries would need to be in the `ProxyControlEAR.ear/lib`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, Yes, I know what you say. But my problem is to understand why using logj4 1.2 there's no need to include the library into the `EAR` file. I add that the class that calls ProxyControl already contains the library and all run under JBoss 7.1 control. But I think the problem is another.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, This from my question: "Some apps to deploy (jar,ear,war), both the new and the old versions, doesn't contains log4j related jars. But the old version is always correctly deployed, while the new has issues."

Comment: The CNFE is for a log4j 2 logger, it has nothing to do with log4j 1. You said you migrated to log4j 2, then all the deployments need visibility to that. The simplest way is to include log4j-api and log4j-core in your EAR.